# Is this electric furnace likely to be insulated with asbestos?

Tags: electrical, furnace, asbestos

I inherited this electric furnace and I'd like to identify the material it's made from. I've not managed to find any record online, but the company itself no longer exists.

[image: furnace controls and id plate]

[image: furnace]

Given its vintage (90s at the very latest, possibly older if the digital control is a more recent addition), and purpose (insulating a very hot thing), something asbestos-based seems fairly likely, but I wouldn't know how to recognise it.

I realise this might not be the very best place to ask the question, but DIY is the only stack exchange site that mentions asbestos. Is it likely to be asbestos?

Comment: Even if it **is** asbestos it likely poses no danger as long as it is in good stable condition. If you see signs of degradation (crumbling, flaky, etc.) or damage which could allow particles of it to become airborne then you would have cause for concern. Also do not drill, sand, cut, etc...

Comment: Find an old timer and buy him a pint to find out about the history of your furnace. I sincerely doubt that it's 90s, unless you were thinking 1890s.